# Passing Bind Variable in case statements in Oracle query

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus, bind-variables

I want to pass Bind Variable (a Date) in a Case statement in order to achieve the following:
When User inputs a date and if that Date is falling on Monday, then the Case statement should fetch the value of Friday (meaning it should bypass the weekends and look for the values of a previous working day)

I tried to use the following query which works well when I use 'sysdate'

```
Select * from table_name
Where tradedate = trunc (sysdate - case to_char(sysdate, 'Dy') 
when 'Mon' then 3 else 1 end);
```

but when I replace 'sysdate' with a Bind Variables, it gives me an error like:

```
tradedate = trunc (:sysdate1 - case to_char(:sysdate2, 'Dy') 
when 'Mon' then 3 else 1 end);
```

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER
> 00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"

Can't we use Bind Variables in Case statement in oracle queries? If so, Can someone please give me any alternate solution to my problem stated above?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Below is the complete code:

```
select * from (
SELECT
    S."TRADEDATE",S."ACCOUNT_NAME",S."BOOKING_AMOUNT",S."ACCOUNT_NUMBER",(CASE WHEN BOOKING_AMOUNT <0 THEN S."CREDIT" ELSE S."DEBIT" END) AS "DEBIT" , (CASE WHEN BOOKING_AMOUNT <0 THEN S."DEBIT"  ELSE S."CREDIT" END) AS "CREDIT",
    U.VALUE_DT , U.AC_NO , NVL(U.BOOKED_AMOUNT ,0) BOOKED_AMOUNT
FROM
    SXB S
    FULL OUTER JOIN UBS U ON
        S.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = U.AC_NO
    AND
        S.TRADEDATE = U.VALUE_DT
       
        UNION ALL
SELECT
BOOKING_DATE TRADEDATE,
'SAXO RECON' ACCOUNT_NAME,
SUM((Case when DR_CR_INDICATOR = 'D' then AMOUNT*-1 when DR_CR_INDICATOR = 'C' then AMOUNT end)) BOOKING_AMOUNT,
EXTERNAL_ACCOUNT ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
'Matched - ' ||A.MATCH_INDICATOR AS DEBIT,
NULL AS CREDIT,
VALUE_DATE VALUE_DT,
NULL AS AC_NO,
0 AS BOOKED_AMOUNT
FROM
    FCUBS.RETB_EXTERNAL_ENTRY A
WHERE A.EXTERNAL_ENTITY = 'SAXODKKKXXX'
      AND A.EXTERNAL_ACCOUNT = '78600/COMMEUR'
    group by
    BOOKING_DATE ,
EXTERNAL_ACCOUNT ,
VALUE_DATE,
MATCH_INDICATOR

order by tradedate, account_name)
where tradedate = trunc (:sysdate1 - case to_char(:sysdate2, 'Dy') when 'Mon' then 3 else 1 end);
```

Comment: Please post complete code, not a snippet

Comment: How are you defining the bind variable ? Inline ?

Comment: Edited my post with the complete code.

Comment: the bind variable is not defined anywhere but it works that way as when I execute this query, it does asks me to enter my value date but then gives the error as mentioned in the post.

Comment: cast the bind variables. e.g. to_date(:sysdate1,'DD-MON-YYYY'), I guess the SQL parser doesn't know the bind variables are going to be dates.

Comment: Thanks Anand. Combining your's and Koen's response I was able to fix the issue in my query. Thanks you so much to you two

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SYSDATE** is a date datatype so oracle will always treat it as a DATE datatype. For a bind variable I'd do an explicit conversion using TO_DATE(:bind_var, 'FORMAT_MASK'). For example:

```
select 
  case TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(:sysdate2,'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'Dy') when 'Mon'
     then 3 
     else 1 
  end from dual
```

Comment: Thanks Koen but it still gives me the same error message.

Comment: Thanks Koen. Combining your's and Anand's response I was able to fix the issue in my query. Thanks you so much to you two :)

Comment: Happy to be of help